# How to mimic a ROW_NUMBER() functionality without using ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've been running into this problem on an exercise and it's driving me crazy that I can't fix it... Basically I'm using SQLLite so I'm limited to using any window functions to get a result and the more painful part is that there is no unique id on the already created schema. See example:

```
**Name,  DateAdded,  Amount**
John,  2015-10-12, 100.00
John,  2015-10-15, 50.00
Aaron, 2015-09-20, 10.00
Paul,  2014-12-20, 24.00
Paul,  2015-12-23, 32.00
```

What is the alternative to using ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Lite when you don't have any unique id to go by ?  I'd like to partition by the name and order by amount.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the more painful part is that there is no unique id on the already created schema" Unless the table was made without the relatively recent `WITHOUT ROWID` clause, use the `rowid` column.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The `rowid` is not guaranteed to have consecutive values. The generic way to get row numbers is to count rows in a subquery.

Comment: @CL - Thanks, but unfortunately that still won't work, as I can't partition due to rows all being duplicate with the value "1" from counting (I would need the first 2 rows to have the RowID of 1 and 2, followed by the third row, RowID = 1 and the forth and fifth row a RowID of 1 and 2 again) and that can't be achieved using COUNT()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all kinds of ugly, but with no windowing functions this is the only way I know of to mimic the `row_number` function:

```
select
  t.Name, t.DateAdded, t.Amount,
  ( select count (*)
     from MyTable u
     where
       t.Name = u.Name and
       t.DateAdded >= u.DateAdded
  ) as row_number
from MyTable t
```

Results:

```
John    2015-10-12  100 1
John    2015-10-15  50  2
Aaron   2015-09-20  10  1
Paul    2014-12-20  24  1
Paul    2014-12-23  32  2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I didn't think of the join on the date using greater or equals to. :-)